# Proper Python syntax and semantics when assigning multiple values to multiple variables on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've recently inherited a number of Python scripts written by a former co-worker and I have been going through the process of reviewing and adding comments to those scripts. In several places throughout the scripts, the original author unpacks and assigns values to multiple variables in a way similar to this:

```
def function_a():
    example_list = ['string',(1,2),{'other_data':[1,2,3]}]
    return example_list

result = function_a()
(x,y) = result[1]
```

The logic definitely follows, but I'm unsure as to why you would need `x` and `y` to be surrounded by parentheses like this. Is this done purely for readability? Or is there some functional difference between expressing this statement as `x, y = result[1]` vs `(x,y) = result[1]`? Unfortunately, I can't run the scripts at the present moment as they require libraries that I'll need to build from source, but I'm nervous to change anything as these scripts operate on databases. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: The parentheses make no difference there - it's the *comma* that's the key syntax. You can test this yourself without running the whole script, `x, y = (1, 2)` vs. `(x, y) = (1, 2)` or even `x, y = 1, 2` and `(x, y) = 1, 2`

Comment: You're correct.  It's a readability thing.  It helps the reader recognize `result[1]` is a tuple